# Mule/dataweave - Unable to get record/item which have date greater than or equal to another date

Tags: xml, datetime, mule, transform, dataweave

I am trying to filter my payload by applying a filter on a date range. Unfortunately, I don't think it works as the data return is invalid. Can you guys help me to check on the cause for this mistake? fyi I already coerce the date data as localdatetime respectively.

Variable

sessionVars.DateFrom = 2017-05-01T00:00:00

sessionVars.DateTo = 2017-09-01T23:59:59

Current Input

```
 <GetListOfCategoriesDetailResponse xmlns="" xmlns:s="">
    <GetListOfCategoriesDetailResult xmlns:a="" xmlns:i="">
        <a:CategoryDetail>
            <a:CategoryCode>ABC456</a:CategoryCode>
            <a:Arrive>2017-12-14T15:00:00</a:Arrive>
            <a:Depart>2018-01-10T15:00:00</a:Depart>
        </a:CategoryDetail>
        <a:CategoryDetail>
            <a:CategoryCode>ABC123</a:CategoryCode>
             <a:Arrive>2017-08-14T15:00:00</a:Arrive>
            <a:Depart>2017-08-20T15:00:00</a:Depart>
        </a:CategoryDetail>
        <a:CategoryDetail>
            <a:CategoryCode>BCD344</a:CategoryCode>
             <a:Arrive>2017-05-14T15:00:00</a:Arrive>
            <a:Depart>2017-06-01T15:00:00</a:Depart>
        </a:CategoryDetail>
    </GetListOfCategoriesDetailResult>
</GetListOfCategoriesDetailResponse>
```

Expected Output

```
<ns0:FoodProducts>
     <ns0:FoodProduct>
         <ns0:FruitTypes>
             <ns0:FruitType FruitTypeCode="ABC123">
          </ns0:FruitType>
             <ns0:FruitType FruitTypeCode="BCD344" >
             </ns0:FruitType>
     </ns0:FoodProduct>
 </ns0:FoodProducts>
```

My thus far dataweave code

```
%output application/xml
 %namespace ns0 
 %namespace ns01 
 %namespace ns1 
 ---
 {
     ns0#FoodProductRS: {
         ns0#FoodProducts: {
             ns0#FoodProduct: {
                 ns0#FruitTypes: {         
  (payload.ns01#GetListOfCategoriesDetailResponse.ns01#GetListOfCategoriesDetailResult.*ns1#CategoryDetail filter (sessionVars.DateTo as :localdatetime {format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}) >= ($.Arrive as :localdatetime {format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"})
                and (sessionVars.DateFrom as :localdatetime {format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}) <= ($.Depart as :localdatetime {format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"})
     map ((categoryDetail , indexOfCategoryDetail) -> {
                         ns0#FruitType @(FruitTypeCode: categoryDetail.ns1#CategoryCode)
                     }))
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reconfirmed that this comparison of code is actually work and I'm able to get the range of records based on the localdatetime comparison.